# Block list of ip addresses linux

Tags: linux, bash, iptables

I'm running Kali on a computer that has port forwarding so I can access it while away from my desk.  Upon looking at /var/log/auth.log I find a number of IP addresses that have been trying to log in which I don't recognise.  I've managed to extract all the IPs and put them in a file, and want to run a script to block them using iptables.  So far, I've come up with this, but it's not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBEROFIPS=cat "ipaddresses.txt" | wc -l
for i in `seq 0 $NUMBEROFIPS`;
 do
        IP=awk 'NR==$i' ipaddresses.txt
        iptables -A INPUT -s $IP -j DROP
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest: `NUMBEROFIPS=$(wc -l < ipaddresses.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r ip; do
  iptables -A INPUT -s "$ip" -j DROP
done < ipaddresses.txt
```

or

```
xargs -I {} iptables -A INPUT -s {} -j DROP < ipaddresses.txt
```